# Sonar Code Coverage widget says No Data

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I have a Sonar 2.10 installation with the C# eco system plugins (1.1-SNAPSHOT compiled yesterday). I am using PartCover 4.0.20908 To generate the coverage report.

The Code Coverage widget shows "No data" although there is a code coverage report generated, like this:

```
<PartCoverReport version="4.0" date="2011-09-19T11:32:08.9219051+02:00">
  <File id="1" url="c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\InternetOfThings\workspace\InternetOfThings\InternetOfThings.Portal\Global.asax.cs" />
  <Assembly id="1" name="InternetOfThings.Portal" module="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\InternetOfThings\workspace\InternetOfThings\InternetOfThings.Portal.Tests\bin\Debug\InternetOfThings.Portal.dll" domain="IsolatedAppDomainHost" domainIdx="1" />
  <Type asmref="1" name="InternetOfThings.Portal.Class1" flags="0">
    <Method methoddef="100663297" name=".ctor" sig="void  ()" bodysize="8" flags="0" iflags="0">
      <pt visit="1" pos="0" len="6" />
      <pt visit="1" pos="6" len="2" />
    </Method>
  </Type>
  <Type asmref="1" name="InternetOfThings.Portal.MvcApplication" flags="0">
    <Method methoddef="100663298" name="RegisterGlobalFilters" sig="void  (System.Web.Mvc.GlobalFilterCollection)" bodysize="15" flags="0" iflags="0">
      <pt visit="0" pos="0" len="1" fid="1" sl="13" sc="9" el="13" ec="10" />
      <pt visit="0" pos="1" len="12" fid="1" sl="14" sc="13" el="14" ec="53" />
      <pt visit="0" pos="13" len="2" fid="1" sl="15" sc="9" el="15" ec="10" />
    </Method>
    <Method methoddef="100663299" name="RegisterRoutes" sig="void  (System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection)" bodysize="52" flags="0" iflags="0">
      <pt visit="0" pos="0" len="1" fid="1" sl="18" sc="9" el="18" ec="10" />
      <pt visit="0" pos="1" len="12" fid="1" sl="19" sc="13" el="19" ec="62" />
      <pt visit="0" pos="13" len="37" fid="1" sl="21" sc="13" el="25" ec="15" />
      <pt visit="0" pos="50" len="2" fid="1" sl="27" sc="9" el="27" ec="10" />
    </Method>
    <Method methoddef="100663300" name="Application_Start" sig="void  ()" bodysize="31" flags="0" iflags="0">
      <pt visit="0" pos="0" len="1" fid="1" sl="30" sc="9" el="30" ec="10" />
      <pt visit="0" pos="1" len="6" fid="1" sl="31" sc="13" el="31" ec="49" />
      <pt visit="0" pos="7" len="11" fid="1" sl="33" sc="13" el="33" ec="58" />
      <pt visit="0" pos="18" len="11" fid="1" sl="34" sc="13" el="34" ec="47" />
      <pt visit="0" pos="29" len="2" fid="1" sl="35" sc="9" el="35" ec="10" />
    </Method>
    <Method methoddef="100663301" name=".ctor" sig="void  ()" bodysize="8" flags="0" iflags="0" />
  </Type>
  <Type asmref="1" name="&lt;&gt;f__AnonymousType0`3" flags="0">
    <Method methoddef="100663302" name=".ctor" sig="void  (, , )" bodysize="29" flags="0" iflags="0" />
    <Method methoddef="100663303" name="get_controller" sig="  ()" bodysize="23" flags="0" iflags="0" />
    <Method methoddef="100663304" name="get_action" sig="  ()" bodysize="23" flags="0" iflags="0" />
    <Method methoddef="100663305" name="get_id" sig="  ()" bodysize="23" flags="0" iflags="0" />
    <Method methoddef="100663306" name="ToString" sig="string  ()" bodysize="131" flags="0" iflags="0" />
    <Method methoddef="100663307" name="Equals" sig="bool  (object)" bodysize="100" flags="0" iflags="0" />
   <Method methoddef="100663308" name="GetHashCode" sig="int  ()" bodysize="99" flags="0" iflags="0" />
 </Type>
</PartCoverReport>
```

Other metrics/widgets like Code Complexity, unit tests, seems to work OK.

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am one of the developers of the sonar C# plugins. You should ask for help using the sonar user mailing list. You can subscribe here : http://www.sonarsource.org/support/support/

That being said, you can get more debug data by adding "-X" to the command line. You can also run maven in debug mode using "mvndebug" instead of "mvn" .

Anyway, my first guess is that you may have found a bug in the coverage/gallio plugin when working on asp.net code.

Hope to hear from you on the user mailing list.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately, I experienced other issues with Sonar and decided it was time to look into another solution. I ended up with TeamCity and have so far been happy with that.

Comment: @Alexandre why require a mailing list instead of an RSS feed, forum, or blog post?

Comment: @Maslow well this is the way the sonar community works. Some contributors work on several plugins beside the C# ones, and so it is better and easier for everyone to use this mailing list.