# coveragexml consist of special character and not importing coverage data in Sonar Dashboard

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarqube5.6, vstest.console.exe

I am creating coverage data from vstest.console.exe and the coverage file is in coveragexml format. Other projects are able to import coverage data but this file is with some special characters and not importing the data into Sonar Dashboard.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<results>
  <modules>
    <module name="se.tsc.gateway.tests.dll" path="se.tsc.gateway.tests.dll" id="8666CE64A1D9D647B882DD709C72AB4901000000" block_coverage="74.31" line_coverage="92.31" blocks_covered="81" blocks_not_covered="28" lines_covered="48" lines_partially_covered="4" lines_not_covered="0">
      <functions>
        <function id="8272" token="0x6000001" name="TestInitialize()" type_name="TSCControllerTest" block_coverage="100.00" line_coverage="100.00" blocks_covered="3" blocks_not_covered="0" lines_covered="4" lines_partially_covered="0" lines_not_covered="0">
          <ranges>
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="22" start_column="9" end_line="22" end_column="10" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="23" start_column="13" end_line="23" end_column="76" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="24" start_column="13" end_line="24" end_column="38" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="25" start_column="9" end_line="25" end_column="10" />
          </ranges>
        </function>
        <function id="8312" token="0x6000008" name="MoveNext()" type_name="TSCControllerTest.GetRequestStatusMethod.&lt;RequestGetTSC_ShouldReturnInvalidCompanyId&gt;d__0" block_coverage="70.83" line_coverage="87.50" blocks_covered="17" blocks_not_covered="7" lines_covered="7" lines_partially_covered="1" lines_not_covered="0">
          <ranges>
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="32" start_column="13" end_line="32" end_column="14" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="34" start_column="17" end_line="34" end_column="96" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="35" start_column="17" end_line="35" end_column="29" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="36" start_column="17" end_line="36" end_column="36" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="37" start_column="17" end_line="37" end_column="44" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="partial" start_line="40" start_column="17" end_line="40" end_column="113" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="43" start_column="17" end_line="43" end_column="71" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="44" start_column="13" end_line="44" end_column="14" />
          </ranges>
        </function>
        <function id="8748" token="0x600000a" name="MoveNext()" type_name="TSCControllerTest.GetRequestStatusMethod.&lt;RequestGetTSC_ShouldReturnInvalidASRInput&gt;d__8" block_coverage="70.83" line_coverage="87.50" blocks_covered="17" blocks_not_covered="7" lines_covered="7" lines_partially_covered="1" lines_not_covered="0">
          <ranges>
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="48" start_column="13" end_line="48" end_column="14" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="50" start_column="17" end_line="50" end_column="96" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="51" start_column="17" end_line="51" end_column="30" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="52" start_column="17" end_line="52" end_column="36" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="53" start_column="17" end_line="53" end_column="38" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="partial" start_line="56" start_column="17" end_line="56" end_column="113" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="59" start_column="17" end_line="59" end_column="70" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="60" start_column="13" end_line="60" end_column="14" />
          </ranges>
        </function>
        <function id="9168" token="0x600000c" name="MoveNext()" type_name="TSCControllerTest.GetRequestStatusMethod.<RequestGetTSC_ShouldReturnInvalidRONumbe>d__10" block_coverage="70.83" line_coverage="87.50" blocks_covered="17" blocks_not_covered="7" lines_covered="7" lines_partially_covered="1" lines_not_covered="0">
          <ranges>
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="64" start_column="13" end_line="64" end_column="14" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="66" start_column="17" end_line="66" end_column="96" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="67" start_column="17" end_line="67" end_column="30" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="68" start_column="17" end_line="68" end_column="37" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="69" start_column="17" end_line="69" end_column="44" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="partial" start_line="72" start_column="17" end_line="72" end_column="113" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="75" start_column="17" end_line="75" end_column="69" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="76" start_column="13" end_line="76" end_column="14" />
          </ranges>
        </function>
        <function id="9612" token="0x600000f" name="&lt;RequestGetTSC_ShouldReturnTSCSettings&gt;b__18(CDK.SE.TSC.GatewayProviderInterface.ITSCProvider)" type_name="TSCControllerTest.GetRequestStatusMethod.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass19" block_coverage="100.00" line_coverage="100.00" blocks_covered="3" blocks_not_covered="0" lines_covered="1" lines_partially_covered="0" lines_not_covered="0">
          <ranges>
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="89" start_column="22" end_line="89" end_column="59" />
          </ranges>
        </function>
        <function id="9656" token="0x6000010" name="MoveNext()" type_name="TSCControllerTest.GetRequestStatusMethod.&lt;RequestGetTSC_ShouldReturnTSCSettings&gt;d__1b" block_coverage="77.42" line_coverage="95.65" blocks_covered="24" blocks_not_covered="7" lines_covered="22" lines_partially_covered="1" lines_not_covered="0">
          <ranges>
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="80" start_column="13" end_line="80" end_column="14" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="82" start_column="17" end_line="82" end_column="96" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="83" start_column="17" end_line="83" end_column="30" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="84" start_column="17" end_line="84" end_column="36" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="85" start_column="17" end_line="85" end_column="44" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="86" start_column="17" end_line="86" end_column="77" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="87" start_column="17" end_line="87" end_column="88" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="88" start_column="17" end_line="91" end_column="41" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="partial" start_line="94" start_column="17" end_line="94" end_column="78" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="97" start_column="17" end_line="97" end_column="116" />
            <range source_id="0" covered="yes" start_line="98" start_column="13" end_line="98" end_column="14" />
          </ranges>
        </function>
      </functions>
      <source_files>
        <source_file id="0" path="d:\BambooBld\SVE-TSCG2-JOB1\TSC\Gateway\SE.TSC.Gateway.Tests\TSCControllerTest.cs">
        </source_file>
      </source_files>
    </module>
  </modules>
</results>
```

The type_name is looking weird and having special characters. Please let me know if this is an issue with vstest.console.exe or c# sonar plugin.

Note: Unit test numbers are showing but not code coverage.

[image]

Comment: What's your encoding? Also, including the full file contents is fine, but please also excerpt the part you find questionable or troublesome.

Comment: if you see the coverage, you can check this "TSCControllerTest.GetRequestStatusMethod.&lt;RequestGetTSC_ShouldReturnInvalidASRInput&gt;d__8" which is not able to parsed by sonar and the coverage is not shown on dashboard.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam we are using this to convert our files https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator/wiki/Visual-Studio-Coverage-Tools

Comment: i can see a similar issue in stackoverflow where method name is with special characters. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7468971/sonar-code-coverage-widget-says-no-data?rq=1

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam any updates on this ??